# Why resharper 7 tests session window does not show unit tests total execution time in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

When I run unit tests and enabling test execution time display by pressing

[image]

this button, Resharper shows me execution time of each of the tests, but not the summary execution time, as on the next screen shot. My question is why and how can I fix or setup that?

[image]

Comment: Dmytro, thanks for report.
[Issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330088) is logged.