# Resharper 7.1 unit test time tracking bug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: resharper

Configuration 
- visual studio 2012
- windows 8
- resharper 7.1.25.234

Accordion to this question
[Why resharper 7 tests session window does not show unit tests total execution time in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530602/why-resharper-7-tests-session-window-does-not-show-unit-tests-total-execution-ti)
was problem in total time, and it should be fixed in 7.1.4.212 build accordion to this issue
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330088

But now this does not work and tracking single time time is broking too

[image]

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: I wasnt able to find a anwser or a issue in the issue tracker of JetBrains so a added one. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336475